# Computation of Gabor transform synthesis integral

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, matlab

I'm reading a monograph where the forward and inverse Gabor transforms are being computed. (See pg. 122 of [Seismic Inverse Q Filtering](http://www.scribd.com/doc/45448335/SEISMIC-INVERSE-q-FILTERING) for further details).  For a time $t$ in a time series $u(t)$, and a window time $\tau$ at the center of a window (a sub-array of the time series with $N$ elements), a Gabor window (with $N$ elements) is defined as the time-domain product:

$u(\tau ,t) = u(t)w(t - \tau )$

The window function is from my other [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163375/infinite-limits-of-integration-with-discrete-sequence):

$
w(t) = \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\frac{2}{{T\sqrt \pi  }}\exp \left[ { - {{\left( {\frac{{2t}}{T}} \right)}^2}} \right],{\rm{  for }} - T \le t \le T}\\
{0,{\rm{ otherwise}}}
\end{array}} \right.
$

The Gabor transform is defined as the Fourier Transform of $u(\tau,t)$.  I think this could also be computed using the FFT:

$U(\tau ,\omega ) = {\rm{FFT}}({\rm{ }}u(\tau ,t){\rm{ }})$

Once the Gabor transform has been computed, the monograph shows how to compute the inverse Gabor transform.  First, using the Inverse Fourier Transform (or IFFT):

${\rm{ }}u(\tau ,t) = {\rm{IFFT(}}U(\tau ,\omega ){\rm{)}}$

Now the monograph refers to a very curious "data synthesis integral" that is used to recompose $u(t)$, the sequence in the time domain:

$u(t) = h(t)\int\limits_{ - \infty }^\infty  {u(\tau ,t)d} \tau $

The $h(t)$ function is given as the following:

$h(t) = {\left[ {\int\limits_{ - \infty }^\infty  w (t - \tau )d\tau } \right]^{ - 1}}$

I am finding it challenging to understand what is meant by the "data synthesis integral", and how the integral allows for the re-computation of the original time series $u(t)$.

How do I numerically compute this integral (listed below)?

$\int\limits_{ - \infty }^\infty  {u(\tau ,t)d} \tau $

Note that the operation of the inverse Gabor transform must be able to reverse the operation of the forward Gabor transform.  I can't understand why the integration is occurring over $\tau$, which should be the window center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation in this monograph is strange.  After some investigation, I would suggest using another paper [1] to compute the Gabor transform, which is nothing more than a Short Time Fourier Transform (STFT) with a Gaussian window.

[1] J. B. Allen and L. R. Rabiner, “A unified approach to short-time Fourier analysis and synthesis,” Proceedings of the IEEE, vol. 65, no. 11, pp. 1558 – 1564, Nov. 1977.

Comment: Did you implement the discrete Gabor transform by some programming language? i.e. Matlab?

Comment: Yes I did; you can look here for the inverse and forward transforms: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2757/inverse-short-time-fourier-transform-algorithm-described-in-words

Comment: Ok thanks! I am trying to understand how the Windowed Fourier transform works, so I used Matlab to create an artificial signal, and plotted the Windowed Fourier transform using a gaussian window. 

![plot][1]

However, sometimes,(i.e. $\frac{1}{2}\leq{t}<\frac{3}{4}$, and $\frac{3}{4}\leq{t}\leq1$), we can see some form of bifurcating effect (vertically). The effect will gradually decrease and disappear, if we use a larger window. Do you know the reason?

  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/DqM4z.png

Comment: This might be due to band-limiting of the input signal by the window size.  I believe that the Allen and Rabiner paper discusses this for the OLA method.